# Estimate HAC Covariance Matrix from data by hand - Newey West

Tags: autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, covariance-matrix, robust-standard-error, neweywest

Given $T$ realizations for $N$ random variables, $X\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times T}$, I want to estimate the **covariance matrix** of the data, $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$. The sample covariance would be $$\hat\Omega_{i,j}=\frac{1}{T-1}\sum_{t=1}^T (X_{i,t}-\bar{X_i})(X_{j,t}-\bar{X_j}).$$
I however want to compute the **hac (heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation) robust covariance matrix**, using for example a **Bartlett kernel**. This is suggested by **Newey and West (1987)**. Their paper is quite technical though and I am not sure how to compute the components of the hac covariance matrix. What would be the formula for $\hat\Omega_{i,j}$ in this case?

---

According to [this description](http://www.eviews.com/help/helpintro.html#page/content/lrvar-Technical_Discussion.html),
\begin{align}
\hat\Omega = \frac{T}{T-K}\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty k(j/b_T)\hat\Gamma_j, \tag{1}
\end{align}
where

- $k$ is the kernel function with bandwitdth $b_T>0$,
- $K$ is the number of parameters and
- $\hat\Gamma_j$ are sample autocorrelations,
  \begin{align*}
  \hat\Gamma_j=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{T}\sum\limits_{t=1+j}^TX_tX_{t-j}' && j\geq0 \\ \\
  \frac{1}{T}\sum\limits_{t=1-j}^TX_t'X_{t+j} && j<0. \end{cases}
  \end{align*}

These are equations (F.4) and (F.5) from [here](http://www.eviews.com/help/helpintro.html#page/content/lrvar-Technical_Discussion.html). Are these formuale correct? Can I set $K=1$ like in the sample covariance matrix? For what $j$ do I truncate the sum in (1)?

Comment: If you use R, achim zeileis "sandwich" package does that sort of thing. There's a nice vignette on it also.

Comment: @mlofton Thanks very much for your comment! I guess you refer to [NeweyWest](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sandwich/versions/3.0-0/topics/NeweyWest) or [vcovHAC](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sandwich/versions/3.0-0/topics/vcovHAC)? Unfortunately, I don't see the formulae these packages employ? Also, most importantly, the input to the functions seems to be a fitted model object (like [in matlab too](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/econ/hac.html)). But I do not have a fitted linear model. I only have realisations of $N$ random variables.

Comment: Hi: I don't know how experienced in R you are, but you can download the sandwich package  and get the source code. If you use linux, download it from cran and then do tar xvfz sandwich_x,x,x,tar.gz. Then the R directory will have the source code in it. Achim writes very nice code, so,  it won't be trivial but it should be possible to figure out how he takes an lm object and calculates the various estimators from it. The details might be discussed in his useR  econometrics book but I don't have that in front of me because I moved.  I'm sorry for the vague advice but that's what I would do.

Comment: Note that there's also a nice vignette ( maybe more than one. I forget ) for the sandwich package on cran which might discuss the formulae. I don't have the time right now to look in detail  but I remember the vignettes being quite enlightening. I would do that first and then go the source code if the vignettes weren't detailed enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably coming in late, but here's the basic idea.

You have some possibly vector-valued time series $\{Z_t\}_{t=1}^T$. More often than not, those would be score functions. For example, if you worked with a linear regression model $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$ (observations as rows), then  you'd use $Z_t = X_t \epsilon_t$ where replacing error terms with estimated residuals makes the estimators we'll see below feasible. Whether this is the case or not, you're interested in estimating the long-run covariance matrix of your vector-valued time series $\{Z_t\}$, i.e.

$$ \Omega_T := \underset{T \rightarrow \infty} \lim T \; \mathbb{E}\left( \bar{Z} \bar{Z}'  \right) $$

where I use $\bar Z := \sum_{t=1}^T Z_t / T$. (The $T$ appears outside because you're normalizing by $\sqrt{T}$). So, how do you do that? Typically, you'll use a weighted sum of sample autocovariances
$$ \Phi_T(\tau) := \sum_{t=\tau+1}^T Z_t Z_{t-\tau}' \; \; 0 \leq \tau \leq T-1 $$
Obviously, you're estimating a covariance matrix so the time series is covariance stationary and we have $\Phi_T(\tau) = \Phi_T(-\tau)'$ for $\tau < 0$. Now, you've probably realized $\Phi_T(T-1)$ would be estimated with just one observation which would most likely not be very precise, so what we tend to do is select weights based on so-called kernels which decay as $\tau$ increases. For Newey and West (1987), for a truncation lag of order $m_T > 0$, the weights are
$$ w(\tau) = 1 - \frac{|\tau|}{m_T + 1}. $$

So, we just need to apply our definition of long-run covariance and replace everything with weighted sample counterparts:
\begin{align}
    \hat{\Omega}_T &= \sum_{\tau=-m_T}^{m_T} \left( 1 - \frac{|\tau|}{m_T + 1} \right) \Phi_T(\tau) \\
                   &= \Phi_T(0) + \sum_{\tau=1}^{m_T} \left( 1 - \frac{|\tau|}{m_T + 1} \right) \left( \Phi_T(\tau) + \Phi_T(\tau)' \right)
\end{align}

where I exploited the symmetries $\Phi_T(\tau) = \Phi_T(-\tau)'$ and $w(\tau) = w(-\tau)$. This gives you directly a simple way to code this. For example, if you have observations as rows and variables as column in an object 'Z' in MATLAB, then

```
Omega = Z'.Z/Tz;
for jj = 1:mT

    % Compute sample autocovariance of order jj
    % NB: Need Zt and Zt-jj to be of the same dim.
    Z0   = Z((1+jj):end,:); 
    Zlag = Z(1:(end-jj),:);
    PhiT = Z0'*Zlag/size(Z0,1);
    
    % Weights (Bartlett)
    wj = 1 - jj/(mT + 1);

    % Update long-run covariance matrix estimate
    Omega = Omega + wj*( PhiT + PhiT' );
end
```

Basically, you start with $\Phi_T(0)$ and then you add up the weighted autocovariances of order 1 through $m_T$. To choose the truncation lag, you can use a rule of thumb like the nearest integer to $0.75T^{1/3}$. You can do more complicated things (optimal bandwidth selection would then require proceeding in steps because the formulas usually involve the unknown parameters you're trying to estimate here).

Comment: Fixed the typo. Thanks.